# Запустить steam-игру через bat-файл

Tags: bat

Я пытаюсь написать `bat` для запуска игры.

Игры, установленные через Steam, нельзя запустить прямым вызовом `.exe`. Поэтому я пытаюсь запустить через Steam.

Пробовал использовать команду вида `steam://run/12345`, но она не работает.

Comment: `start steam://rungameid/246620`. перенесу в ответ, если вопрос переоткроют.

Comment: а можно ли запустить игру без самого стим? то есть надо что-то послать ехе файлу игры, верно? сама игра запускается нормально. но затык в том, что внутри игры есть магазин, который вобще-то никоем образом со стим не связан - игровая валюта, зарабатываемая игровым путем, может быть потрачена в этом магазине. так вот при тырке на эту вкладку - игра зависает. когда запускал из под стима - все работало замечательно. просто на ХР стим давно умер. может можно что-то добавить в ярлыке к ехе файлу игры, чтобы он начал думать что он запущен из под стима?

Answer (score 4):

Команду можно подсмотреть, создав для игры ярлык на рабочем столе.

Для запуска url (не только `steam://`, а с любым протоколом) из командной строки можно использовать start:

```
start steam://rungameid/246620
```

Answer (score 1):

Меня всегда удивляла командная строка под Windows... Можно написать такой bat-файл для запуска игры

```
@ECHO OFF
set cmd="C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe <game>"
for /f %%i in ('%cmd%')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
Start "" /MIN "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe" -login login password -applaunch 730
exit
```

Запуск стима и игры сразу. В данном примере запускается CS:GO (appid 730)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой bat-скрипт:

> start "путь к steam.exe" "путь к .exe игры"

Пример:

> start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\game.exe"